# How can I reach an object or array inside the dataframe column?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am currently trying to visualize a json file on python. I have to reach "duration" and "distance" values inside the "match_result" object.

While it is a json file, I can reach them by writing these codes on python:
`print(matches[0]["match_result"]["matchings"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"])`
and
`print(matches[0]["match_result"]["matchings"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"])`

[image]

But since I could not write for loops to visualize and since I am more comfortable working on a csv file, I converted it to csv. And it looks like this now:[image]

I tried to reaching them by writing `data.match_result[1268].matchings[0]` or `data.match_result[1268]["matchings"][0]` but, of course they did not work.

So, my question is how can I reach these values on a data frame and how can I move them to a new column?

Comment: You have to convert the json to an object.  `obj = json.loads(data.match_result[1268])`  ; `obj["matchings"][0]["legs"]`.

Comment: I get this error: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1). When I write ```obj = json.loads(data.match_result[1268])```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'driver': 'john', 'test': {'car': [{'brand': 'ford', 'condition': 'beater'}, {'brand': 'chev', 'condition': 'new'}]}}])                                                                    

In [29]: df.test.iloc[0]['car']                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[29]: 
[{'brand': 'ford', 'condition': 'beater'},
 {'brand': 'chev', 'condition': 'new'}]

In [30]: df.test.iloc[0]['car'][0]                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[30]: {'brand': 'ford', 'condition': 'beater'}
```

Long story short, try:

```
data.match_result.iloc[1268].matchings[0]
```

Comment: I get this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'matchings' when I write ```data.match_result.iloc[1268].matchings[0]``` also tried as you write on your answer like this: ```data.match_result.iloc[1268]['matchings'][0]``` but this time getting this error: string indices must be integers

Comment: What type does pandas think match_results is

Comment: Based on the table, it's a string -- a JSON record.  You will have to pass data.match_result.iloc[1268] to json.loads, and then manipulate that object.

Comment: As  I mentioned before, I get this error: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1). When I write``` obj = json.loads(data.match_result[1268])```